# Change UIButton's default titleColor

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am looking for the simple way to set `UIButton's` default `titleColor` to custom one at app start. But I want to respect the case, when `titleColor` is not default and has custom value. `[[UIButton appearance] setTitleColor: forState:]` allows me to set custom color for all buttons at once. However it overrides already set custom color. 
Is there any fast way to override default title color and respect custom color at the same time?

Comment: [button setTitleColor:[UIColor YourColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; Please search your ans before asking question

Comment: in such manner I need to set button's color every time programmatically at every controller. But I desire to ovveride default color once at app start. But with respect the case, when color already set in interface builder to custom value(not default color option), the custom color should not be overriden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `appearance` as you do for setting global appearance (all buttons) and **instance method** `[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];` for setting a color just for one button.

Comment: @nyekimov Is this what you need?

Comment: Yep, man. That is really what I need. I tried setting color customly by interface builder, obviously appearance ovverides it. However your programmatical suggestion works wine.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try to this.....

    create catagory class for UIButton like bellow

    Sample.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface Sample : UIButton

    @end

    Sample.m
    #import "Sample.h"

    @implementation Sample
    -(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
    {
        self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
        if (self) {
            [self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
        }
        return self;
    }

    @end


    and After crate class use this class as Custom Class Like

![Image][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXYfY.png
```